# Build not showing up in App Store Connect - not receiving any status e-mail

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

Somehow my new build from Xcode is not showing up in App Store Connect. It's showing up in the Activity tab for a quick second, then disappears to no where to be found. I did not receive any e-mail from Apple because of Plist errors or anything alike. I did check the correct e-mail address, I've received e-mails like this before on the exact same address and I was just informed yesterday about a successfully processed build on this address. However, not a single e-mail about this particular build - it just disappears.
When I try to upload the same build number again, I get the `Redundant Binary Upload` error. Tried increasing the build number and reuploading, no success, same behavior.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same error right now. No errors and no status e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this type of problem in my past. After some research i got solution for that.

There should be some privacy key usage description missing in your **info.plist** like you are using location in your app or third party framework but you didn't add location privacy key usage description in your info.plist.

I added those missing keys in **info.plist** and then it's working fine.

Comment: I also face the same issue resolve by above mentioned solution.